# How to adjust the ratio while observing other rows with same properties

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider the following dataframe:

```
tdf=pd.DataFrame({'City':['NY','NY','NY','NY','NY','CA','CA','CA','CA','CA','CA'],'PRJ':['A','B','C','D','E','F','GG','GG','I','J','K'],'Year':[2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2011,2012,2012,2013,2014,2015],'EXPECTED':[2,3,4,6.1,7,7.1,8,3,10,11,11],'ACTUAL':[0.5,1.8,2.7,5.1,5.8,6.8,10,10,8,8.1,8.2]})
```

[image]

My goal is to add a `ratio=actual/expected.` If I didn't have project GG that would have been a trivial:

```
tdf['Ratio']=tdf['ACTUAL']/tdf['EXPECTED']
```

[image]

Given this challenge, what I wish to do is to add another column **ACTUAL_ADJUSTED** where I **'pro-rate' the ACTUAL** like this:

```
prj_ratio = 10/(8+3) = 0.909
gg6_actual = (0.909*8)=7.272
gg7_actual = (0.909*3)=2.727
```

**What have I tried?**
I built a function

```
def make_adjustments(r): 
    s = tdf[(tdf['City']==r['City']) & (tdf['Year']==r['Year']) ]
    if len(s)>1:
        return "problem here" 
    else:
        return 'ok'


tdf['ACTUAL_ADJUSTED'] = tdf.apply(make_adjustments,axis=1)
```

This function will identify the problem but in reality (in my real data) it takes a significant amount of time. So I concluded that I'm not on the right track. Any idea how to solve this properly?

Comment: So we can assume all `actual` of `GG`. or any project with more than one record, are the same?

Comment: You sure (0.909*8)*8= 7.272 ? should it be 58.176

Comment: @WeNYoBen i'm guess OP means weighted average, only one multipliation

Comment: I changed it thanks for noticing

Comment: @QuangHoang yes, for one record assume correct ration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
def adjust(x):
    if len(x)==1:
        return x['ACTUAL']/x['EXPECTED']
    else:
        return x['ACTUAL'] * x['EXPECTED'] / x['EXPECTED'].sum()


tdf['RATIO'] = (tdf.groupby(['City', 'Year'])
                .apply(adjust).
                reset_index(level=[0,1], drop=True)
               )
```

Output:

```
+-----+-------+------+-------+-----------+---------+----------+
|     | City  | PRJ  | Year  | EXPECTED  | ACTUAL  |  RATIO   |
+-----+-------+------+-------+-----------+---------+----------+
|  0  | NY    | A    | 2011  | 2.0       | 0.5     | 0.250000 |
|  1  | NY    | B    | 2012  | 3.0       | 1.8     | 0.600000 |
|  2  | NY    | C    | 2013  | 4.0       | 2.7     | 0.675000 |
|  3  | NY    | D    | 2014  | 6.1       | 5.1     | 0.836066 |
|  4  | NY    | E    | 2015  | 7.0       | 5.8     | 0.828571 |
|  5  | CA    | F    | 2011  | 7.1       | 6.8     | 0.957746 |
|  6  | CA    | GG   | 2012  | 8.0       | 10.0    | 7.272727 |
|  7  | CA    | GG   | 2012  | 3.0       | 10.0    | 2.727273 |
|  8  | CA    | I    | 2013  | 10.0      | 8.0     | 0.800000 |
|  9  | CA    | J    | 2014  | 11.0      | 8.1     | 0.736364 |
| 10  | CA    | K    | 2015  | 11.0      | 8.2     | 0.745455 |
+-----+-------+------+-------+-----------+---------+----------+
```

Or if you want the 'ACTUAL_ADJUSTED' column in your sample:

```
tdf['ACTUAL_ADJUSTED'] = (tdf.groupby(['City', 'Year'])
                          .ACTUAL.transform(lambda x: 
                                            'OK' if len(x)==1 
                                                 else 'problem here')
                         )
```

Comment: B.E.A.U.T.I.F.U.L! Thanks!

Comment: would you mind to elaborate what is 'reset_index(level=[0,1]' thank you

Comment: @adhg after `groupby(['City', 'Year'])`, the (sub)dataframe passed to `adjust` is triple-indexed by `City, Year` and the original `index`. So is the series returned by `adjust`. Now if you want to assign this series to the original dataframe, you need them to have the same index. That's why you need to free the first two levels of the returned series' index. To see better what I mean, run the `(tdf.groupby...` part without `reset_index`.

Answer (score 1):

If that is the case using `transform` with `nunique` then `np.where`

```
s=tdf.groupby(['City','PRJ'])['EXPECTED'].transform('nunique')
s1=tdf.groupby(['City','PRJ'])['EXPECTED'].transform('sum')
tdf['ACTUAL_ADJUSTED']=np.where(s>1,'problem here','ok')
tdf['value']=np.where(s==1,tdf.ACTUAL/df.EXPECTED,tdf.ACTUAL/s1*tdf.EXPECTED)

tdf
Out[728]: 
   City PRJ  Year  EXPECTED  ACTUAL     Ratio ACTUAL_ADJUSTED     value
0    NY   A  2011       2.0     0.5  0.250000              ok  0.250000
1    NY   B  2012       3.0     1.8  0.600000              ok  0.600000
2    NY   C  2013       4.0     2.7  0.675000              ok  0.675000
3    NY   D  2014       6.1     5.1  0.836066              ok  0.836066
4    NY   E  2015       7.0     5.8  0.828571              ok  0.828571
5    CA   F  2011       7.1     6.8  0.957746              ok  0.957746
6    CA  GG  2012       8.0    10.0  1.250000    problem here  7.272727
7    CA  GG  2012       3.0    10.0  3.333333    problem here  2.727273
8    CA   I  2013      10.0     8.0  0.800000              ok  0.800000
9    CA   J  2014      11.0     8.1  0.736364              ok  0.736364
10   CA   K  2015      11.0     8.2  0.745455              ok  0.745455
```

Comment: Thanks! Works. I fixed a small typo